# Remove duplicates from array and create a new array

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I want to remove all the duplicates in this array and I can't quite make it work. When all the duplicates are removed, I want to create a new array without the removed numbers. Here's my code:

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] s = { 11, 11, 12, 12, 13, 13, 14, 15, 16 };
        int[] q = s.Distinct().ToArray();

        Console.WriteLine(q.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

This prints the array {11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16}; but I wanted it to print the array {14, 15, 16}.

Comment: You have successfully created an array without any duplicates.  Well done /patsback.

Comment: `q.ToString()` is pointless if you don't want to know the full name of the array-type. Use `string.Join(",", q)` instead.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Yes. And then I want to write it out in my console application.

Comment: `new [] { 11, 11 }.Distinct().ToArray()` returns `int[]{ 11 }`. It looks like you're expecting it to return an empty set.

Comment: A quick suggestion for future questions: include what you *expect* the output to be, in other words, say whats wrong with the code provided. My guess what just that, and what you were looking for was not obvious given the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
int[] s = { 11, 11, 12, 12, 13, 13, 14, 15, 16 };
var NotDuplicateItems = s.GroupBy(r => r)
    .Where(grp => grp.Count() == 1)
    .Select(r => r.Key)
    .ToArray();
```

The above will give you items which are not duplicate in the array `s`

Answer (score 1):

`Distinct` returns a collection with all duplicate entries removed. It does not, however, remove the original items (that were later duplicated).

To remove all items that are duplicated, that is, that have a "Count" greater than 1:

```
int[] q = s.Where(i => s.Count(j => j == i) == 1).ToArray();
```

This is O(n^2), so don't do it over a large collection.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but it's probably because this code won't compile as written (see the `q` inside the lambda [you mean `s`, but you typoed it]).

Answer (score 1):

If you know your input array is going to be sorted (it is in your example), you should take advantage of that. If you do, you can iterate over the array once:

```
public int[] RemoveDuplicates(int[] source)
{
    bool occurredOnce = true;
    int currentItem = source[0];

    var result = new List<int>();

    for (int i = 1; i < source.Length; i++)
    {
        if (source[i] != currentItem)
        {
            if (occurredOnce)
            {
                result.Add(currentItem);
            }

            currentItem = source[i];
            occurredOnce = true;
        }
        else 
        {
            occurredOnce = false;
        }
    }

    if (occurredOnce)
    {
        result.Add(currentItem);
    }

    return result.ToArray();
}
```

**Example:** https://dotnetfiddle.net/4qgEFs

Comment: @BradleyDotNET: Mmm, don't think so. When the first 12 is encountered, `occurredOnce` will be `false`-- the last iteration evaluated the second 11. The `if` block that would add 11 gets skipped, and `currentItem` and `occurredOnce` get reset. On the subsequent iteration, where `currentItem` is equal to 12, the `occurredOnce` flag will be set to `false`. I updated my answer with a working example.

Answer (score -1):

I cant code it at the moment.. but here is my thought process....

Take the first number, then remove it from the rest of the string (or array).

Then search for that number that was just removed in the string (or array).

If it finds it again, it wont print the number. If it doesnt - then the number is shown.

Comment: That works ok if you are just printing, but getting the final collection, then printing it, would be much more useful generally.